# Traversing an XML tree without namespace in Python

Tags: python, xml, xpath

I am parsing a large XML file, which essentially contains a table. The nodes in the XML don't always have names. Nested deep within several tags is what is basically an HTML-like table with `<TD>`s containing raw (numeric) data within row ( `<TR>` ) tags. Now before I can iterate through to the table there is a whole bunch of metadata tags that I'm not interested in. For instance:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="--ommitted--" xmlns:xsi="--ommitted--">
    <soap:Body>
        <FetchReportResponse xmlns="URL1">
            <FetchReportResult xmlns="URL2">
                <REPORT>
                    <TITLE>CROSS VISITING REPORT</TITLE>
                    <SUBTITLE/>
                    <SUMMARY>
                        <GEOGRAPHY>--ommitted--</GEOGRAPHY>
                        <LOCATION>--ommitted--</LOCATION>
                        <TIMEPERIOD>--ommitted--</TIMEPERIOD>
                        <TARGET>--ommitted--</TARGET>
                        <MEDIA>--ommitted--</MEDIA>
                        <DATE>--ommitted--</DATE>
                        <USER>--ommitted--</USER>
                    </SUMMARY>
                    <TABLE>
                        <THEAD>
                            <TR>
                              <TH>--ommitted--</TH>
                              <TD>--ommitted--</TD>
                              <TD>--ommitted--</TD>
                              <TD>--ommitted--</TD>
                              <TD>--ommitted--</TD>
                              <TD>--ommitted--</TD>
                              <TD>--ommitted--</TD>
```

I am new to XML parsing so I'm following [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support). I have the following code to read and XML file and create an ElementTree object.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('./../filename.xml')
print(root.find("./"))
```

This understandably prints the following:

```
<Element '{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope' at 0x00000230CAC23318>
```

However, when I try to use the XPath convention to traverse it from here on, I'm unable to. For instance,

```
print(root.find("./Body"))
```

prints `None`, even though `<Body>` is clearly nested inside `<Envelope>`.

EDIT: Following Mark Tolonen's answer I was able to get to the `Body` tag, but how do I get beyond that? More specifically, I want to reach the `<TABLE>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the XPath section, you also need to *pay attention to [the Namespaces section](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces) of the documentation*, since your XML contains various namespaces, with and without prefix (the latter known as default namespace). Notice that `TABLE` element inherits namespace from the nearest ancestor with default namespace: `FetchReportResult`. So to find `TABLE` you need to use the default namespace URI `"URL2"`, either using curly braces syntax or using prefix-URI dictionary :

```
ns = { "u2": "URL2" }
tables = root.findall(".//u2:TABLE", ns)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the fully qualified name, since it is `soap:Body`, you want to qualify body with the `xmlns:soap` value, which (implied from your Envelope example) is:

```
print(root.find("./{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body"))
```

Comment: thank you. And what if I want to get to `FetchReportResponse` and `FetchReportResult`?

Comment: @wrahool Tack on more path `/FetchReportResponse`, etc.   The remaining tags didn't have namespace qualifiers, so they don't need anything special.